# FabricJS. How to add dimensions displaying in controls?

Tags: fabricjs

[image]

How to add dimensions displaying in controls like on screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a text object and set it hidden. And when you are scalling object set the scale width and height to hidden text and make visible. On object modified set visible false to the text.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
canvas.setHeight(200);
canvas.setWidth(300);
var dimText = new fabric.Text("demo", {
  fontSize: 15,
  visible: false
});
canvas.add(dimText);
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  left: 15,
  top: 15,
  radius: 20,
  fill:'',
  stroke: 'red'
});
canvas.add(circle);
var text = new fabric.Text("2018", {
  padding: 30,
  lineHeight: 30
});
canvas.add(text);
canvas.centerObject(text);
text.setCoords();
canvas.on('object:scaling', function(option) {
  var object = option.target;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(option.e);
  dimText.set({
    left: pointer.x - 20,
    top: pointer.y - 20,
    text: parseInt(object.width * object.scaleX) + 'x' + parseInt(object.height * object.scaleY),
    visible: true
  })
});
canvas.on('object:modified', function(option) {
  dimText.set('visible', false);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.7/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, but can i add this for all objects in canvas? (something like canvas.on('object:scaling')? And also it need to be visible when object is selected. (in this case i can use selection:created as i guess)

Comment: @user2455079 , yes. Check Updated answer.